# Renci.Sshnet Using vim

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I would like to use vim with renci.sshnet. What should I do?

I want to use it like a putty or a terminal.

```
using renci.sshnet; 
//.... 
using (var ssh = new SshClient("192.168.51.128", "root", "passwd")) 
{ 
   try 
   { 
      Console.WriteLine("Connected...\n"); 
      ssh.Connect();
      Console.WriteLine("walcome server\n"); 
      while (true)
      { 
         string command = Console.ReadLine(); 
         if (command == "" || command == null)
         { 
            command = "\n"; 
         } 
         SshCommand sshcmd = ssh.RunCommand(command);
         Console.WriteLine(sshcmd.Result);
      } 
      ssh.Disconnect(); 
   } 
   catch (Exception err) 
   { 
      Console.WriteLine(err); 
   } 
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

If you run a vim editor, as shown in the picture, it becomes unresponsive[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/300IF.png)

Comment: You must create a terminal emulator. But with the code above,
The vim does not work. What needs to be corrected?

Comment: So you actually want to implement a generic terminal emulator, right?

Comment: That is accurate.

Comment: I'm sorry. saw it, but I didn't know it was.